# Why is my text not centering with this code And why does the hidden class not activate? (Updated question)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a snake game and tried centering certain elements of my HTML website, as seen in the CSS code below. On top of that I have a Game Over message that should stay hidden until the game ends. However some of my formatting does not get applied with my code and for some reason the hidden class does not activate even after adding a button.

I tried assigning the hidden class and then removing it once the game ends, however for some reason the text is viewable from the beginning of my program. Since this is my first time asking a question and someone said I should show more of my code, I am going to add the whole code. I do apologize if this is too much. I am a beginner at coding and even though I am starting to understand some stuff there is still much I do not understand.

```js
const board_border = 'black';
const board_background = 'white';
const snake_color = 'lightblue';
const snake_border = 'darkblue';

let snake = [{
    x: 200,
    y: 200
  },
  {
    x: 190,
    y: 200
  },
  {
    x: 180,
    y: 200
  },
  {
    x: 170,
    y: 200
  },
  {
    x: 160,
    y: 200
  }
];

let score = 0;
let changing_direction = false;
let food_x;
let food_y;
let dx = 10;
let dy = 0;

const snakeboard = document.getElementById("snakeboard");
const snakeboard_ctx = snakeboard.getContext("2d");

gen_food();
main();

function main() {

  changing_direction = false;
  clear_board();
  drawFood();
  drawSnake();
  move_snake();

  if (!has_game_ended()) {
    setTimeout(main, 200);
  } else {
    const gameOverMessage = document.getElementById("gameOverMessage");
    gameOverMessage.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}

function toggleHiddenClass() {
  document.querySelector('#gameOverMessage').classList.toggle('hidden');
}

function clear_board() {
  snakeboard_ctx.fillStyle = board_background;
  snakeboard_ctx.strokeStyle = board_border;
  snakeboard_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, snakeboard.width, snakeboard.height);
  snakeboard_ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, snakeboard.width, snakeboard.height);
}

function gen_food() {
  food_x = random_food(0, snakeboard.width - 10);
  food_y = random_food(0, snakeboard.height - 10);

  for (const part of snake) {
    if (part.x === food_x && part.y === food_y) {
      return gen_food();
    }
  }
}

function drawFood() {
  snakeboard_ctx.fillStyle = 'lightgreen';
  snakeboard_ctx.strokestyle = 'darkgreen';
  snakeboard_ctx.fillRect(food_x, food_y, 10, 10);
  snakeboard_ctx.strokeRect(food_x, food_y, 10, 10);
}

function drawSnake() {
  snake.forEach(drawSnakePart);
}

function drawSnakePart(snakePart) {
  snakeboard_ctx.fillStyle = snake_color;
  snakeboard_ctx.strokeStyle = snake_border;
  snakeboard_ctx.fillRect(snakePart.x, snakePart.y, 10, 10);
  snakeboard_ctx.strokeRect(snakePart.x, snakePart.y, 10, 10);
}

function has_game_ended() {
  for (let i = 4; i < snake.length; i++) {
    if (snake[i].x === snake[0].x && snake[i].y === snake[0].y) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  const hitLeftWall = snake[0].x < 0;
  const hitRightWall = snake[0].x >= snakeboard.width;
  const hitTopWall = snake[0].y < 0;
  const hitBottomWall = snake[0].y >= snakeboard.height;
  return hitLeftWall || hitRightWall || hitTopWall || hitBottomWall;

}

function random_food(min, max) {
  return Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min) + min) / 10) * 10;
}

function change_direction(event) {
  const LEFT_KEY = 37;
  const RIGHT_KEY = 39;
  const UP_KEY = 38;
  const DOWN_KEY = 40;

  const keyPressed = event.keyCode;
  const goingUp = dy === -10;
  const goingDown = dy === 10;
  const goingRight = dx === 10;
  const goingLeft = dx === -10;

  if (keyPressed === LEFT_KEY && !goingRight) {
    dx = -10;
    dy = 0;
  }

  if (keyPressed === UP_KEY && !goingDown) {
    dx = 0;
    dy = -10;
  }

  if (keyPressed === RIGHT_KEY && !goingLeft) {
    dx = 10;
    dy = 0;
  }

  if (keyPressed === DOWN_KEY && !goingUp) {
    dx = 0;
    dy = 10;
  }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', change_direction);

function move_snake() {
  const head = {
    x: snake[0].x + dx,
    y: snake[0].y + dy
  };
  snake.unshift(head);

  const has_eaten_food = snake[0].x === food_x && snake[0].y === food_y;
  if (has_eaten_food) {
    score += 10;
    document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;
    gen_food();
  } else {
    snake.pop();
  }
}
```

```css
.h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-small;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.p1 {
  text-align: left;
  -indent: 1cm;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: italic;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(96, 89, 80);
}

#snakeboard {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 500px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#gameOverMessage {
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 150px;
  color: rgb(235, 28, 28);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Antic+Slab" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 class="h1">My own snakegame</h1>
<p class="p1">Score:</p>
<div id="score"></div>
<canvas id="snakeboard" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<button type="button" onclick="toggleHiddenClass()">toggle hidden class</button>
<div id="gameOverMessage" class="hidden">
  Game Over!
</div>
```

Comment: The Game Over message works correctly when I run your code.